# Prove that among the numbers $d_1=x_2-x_1, d_2=x_3-x_2,...,d_{101}=x_{201}-x_{101}$ at least $26$ equals.

Tags: contest-math

> Let $x_1<x_2<...<x_{102}\le254 -$ positive integers. Prove that among the numbers $d_1=x_2-x_1, d_2=x_3-x_2,...,d_{101}=x_{102}-x_{101}$ at least $26$ equals.

*Tell me how to solve this problem. I have no idea how to solve this problem.*

Comment: The title says 201 instead of 102 BTW

Comment: You have selected the tag "contest maths". Could you say which contest it is ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that:
$\sum_{i=1}^{101} d_i=x_{102}-x_1\leq 253$.

Now, note that in sequence $(d_i)_i$ you have 101 elements, all of them are positive (!) integers. Assume the opposite, i.e. there are at most $25$ equal elements in this sequence. Let us find a lower bound on the sum $\sum d_i$.

There are at most 25 elements equal 1, at most 25 elements equal 2, etc., so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{101} d_i\geq 25*1+25*2+25*3+25*4+5,$$
the last element comes from the observation that we have 101 $d_i$'s.

But then $\sum_{i=1}^{101}d_i\geq 255$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, there must be at least 26 equal elements in $(d_i)^{101}_{i=1}$

Comment: in the first inequality, the > should be reversed

Comment: Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is that a lot of the differences have to be the same. Why? Because $102$ integers are squeezed between $1$ and $254$ so there can't be too many big jumps. Now we formalize this idea.

Let $\Delta_i$ = $x_{i +1} - x_i.$ Thus, 
$$x_{102} = (x_{102} - x_{101}) + (x_{101} - x_{100}) + \cdots + (x_2 - x_1) + x_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^{101} \Delta_i + x_1.$$

Let $S = \sum_{i = 1}^{101} \Delta_i$. The equation above tells us

$x_{102} = S+ x_1 \le 254.$ Since $x_1 \ge 1$, we have $S \le 253.$

Now suppose that each $\Delta_i$ can be repeated at most $25$ times. Since there are $101$ $\Delta_i$ values, we have $$S \ge 1 \cdot 25 + 2 \cdot 25  + 3 \cdot 25 + 4 \cdot 25 + 1 = 255.$$

This contradicts $S \le 253$ which means that $26$ of the $\Delta_i$ values are equal.

Comment: I discarded the preparation of my answer since it is identical !

Answer (score 1):

In this problem each x_i is positive integer and they are ordered in strictly increasing manner.So,the least value that d_i  can take is 1.If we can show that without permitting a minimum of 26 same values of d_i's we can not accommodate all of the x_i's 0

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is just $25$ equal $d_i$. The minimun possible is $x_{k+1}-x_k=1$ for $k=1,2,...,25$ and $x_{26}=26$.

Now in order to have the other $d_{26+k}$ distinct we must have at the minimum case $x_{27}=28,x_{28}=31,x_{29}=35$ an so on, for which we have $d_{27}=2,d_{28}=3,d_{29}=4...$ This would give $$x_{102}-x_{101}=\frac{76\cdot77}{2}=2926$$ This is impossible because $x_{101}\lt x_{102}\le 254$.

Thus, in this minimal case there are at least two of the $d_i$ equal.

Comment: That was my first approach but I had to wonder that 2926 was such a huge number compared to 254.  You have to take into account they aren't asking prove at most 76 are are distinct but that at least 26 are equal.  we need to rule out we can't have 25 equal one thing and 25 equal another.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is $x_{102} > \sum d_i$.   This is intuitive to me because to get to from one $x_i$ to the next we have to add an $d_i$ to the $x_i$ so the last $x_i$ is greater than the sum of all $x_i$.  But to prove it formally:

$\sum d_i = \sum_{i=2}^{102}(x_i - x_{i-1})$ which is a telescoping sum.

$\sum_{i=2}^{102}(x_i - x_{i-1})= \sum_{i=2}^{102}x_i - \sum_{i=2}^{102}x_{i-1}=$

$\sum_{i=2}^{102}x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{101}x_{i} = x_{102} - x_1$

which is actually stronger and more specific than I first thought.

To prove that there are two equal anything, just screams "pigeon hole" principal at me.  To prove a "pigeon hole" result I usually assume everything is different and show that results in something not fitting.

So what happens if at most there are 25 equal $d_i$.  Well then there must be at least 76 with different values.  If there are 25 of a second value, and 25 or a third and four.  There must be at least four different values. And one fifth value.

If I make these 4 values as small as possible (1,2,3,4) what happens?  Well the sum of those must be at least some minimum value.

$\sum d_i \ge 25*1 + 25*2 + 25*3 + 25* 4 = 250$.

250 is very close to the maximum, I allowed $\sum d_i < x_{102} \le 254$.

Well, I've accounted for 100 of the differences so there is one more.  It must be at least $5$.  So $\sum d_i \ge 255$ which is  contradiction.

Of, course I have to convince myself that $25*1 + 25*2 + 25*3 + 25* 4 + 5$ is the lowest possible sum.  Which is obvious if I replaced any $d_i$ I'd have to replace it with something larger.